# Amend boot cmdline in custom image build

Tags: linux, boot, yocto, bitbake

I'm building a custom image that uses the `meta-intel` layer (*I'm targeting Intel boards, such as the **Minnowboard Turbot**, for instance*), and I want to tweak the options for booting.

#### First problem

As far as I understand, `meta-intel` uses `systemd-boot` (via `rmc-boot`) as EFI_PROVIDER.

So I should be able to override the specific `BOOT_TIMEOUT` parameter by setting :

`SYSTEMD_BOOT_TIMEOUT := "0"`

in my custom image, as far as I can see in [this file](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/classes/systemd-boot.bbclass)

Unfortunately, that doesn't work (the boot timeout is still 4 seconds). How come ?

#### Second problem

As well, I would like to append options to the `boot.conf` file (in `/boot/loader/entries`, loaded by `/boot/loader/loader.conf`), such as `quiet`, or `vt.global_cursor_default=0` for instance.

I see in the [Intel machine conf](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-intel/tree/conf/machine/intel-corei7-64.conf#n41) that there is an `APPEND` configuration, but overriding it or appending to it in my custom image doesn't work (*it's still not written in the boot.conf file*) :

`APPEND += "quiet vt.global_cursor_default=0"`

I've checked that the configuration is correctly read and it's the case :

```
$ bitbake my-custom-image -e | grep ^APPEND= -A1 -B1
#   " quiet rootwait console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0${@bb.utils.contains("IMAGE_FEATURES", "read-only-rootfs", " ro", "", d)}"
APPEND=" quiet vt.global_cursor_default=0 rootwait console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0"
#
```

But no matter what I do, the command line doesn't change on the built image.

What do I miss ? There should be a relatively easy way to achieve what I'm after I guess, but so far I have not managed to do it.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did You try clean up this task's (recipes) and rebuild without cache ?

Comment: I always do a `bitbake -c clean my-custom-image` but do you mean I need a stronger cleaning like `cleanall` maybe ?

Comment: Well It's look like somehow You changes are not swapped correctly and I'm was curious did You are cleaning WS - I don't think that *cleanall* task will helps here (with tmp/work/<arch name>/<PV>/temp/log.task_order file You can check if task was taken from cache). Did You changing original files or did You apply this configs in some global file like conf/local.conf ?

Comment: I tried adding APPEND in `conf.local`, and in a custom distro in my own layer (`conf/distro/my-distro.conf`), to no avail

Comment: I use `meta-intel` here, too (pretty new project I took over from someone else, I don't understand all the details yet.) It boots and so far I had no need to tweak the booting. It is my understanding that I do not use a bootmanager at all, but boot the EFI stub, which is part of the linux kernel. Still I can see `EFI_PROVIDER="rmc-boot"` in my image environment. The `systemd-boot` and `rmc-*` recipies don't get built here, despite being part of the added layer. Are you sure that you are actually using the bootmanager?

Comment: rmc-boot in turns invocates systemdboot, that reads `/boot/loader` files. I'm pretty sure that it is used, I can see these files on the image, I can change them so that the boot is quiet. But I can't manage to do this in Yocto

Comment: While I'm pretty sure this is what's done in the build, I admit I'm still a little confused too about what's booting what, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at the kernel command line parameters for intel platform in Yocto with the meta-intel.

I have noticed differences between the wic and hddimg yocto images.

The hddimg seems to use the rmc boot entry definition whereas the wic image uses the boot entry defined in the wks kickstart.

My machine conf has the following :

```
WKS_FILE ?= "${@bb.utils.contains_any("EFI_PROVIDER", "systemd-boot rmc-boot", "systemd-bootdisk.wks", "mkefidisk.wks", d)}"
```

In turns systemd-bootdisk.wks has the following boot entry "boot" :

```
bootloader --ptable gpt --timeout=5 --append="rootwait rootfstype=ext4 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0"
```

The RMC definition for my Minnowboard Max has 2 entry a boot and an install.

```
Minnow Max B3 boot
Minnow Max B3 install
```

I am using the pyro release for Yocto. Perhaps integration of RMC boot definition has been integrated into the wic images.
I am looking for a common place to add the kernel command line parameter. Any idea ?